# For Jenkins ver. 1.630, i installed Delivery Pipeline plugin, now jenkins failed to boot with below error

Tags: jenkins

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237) Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)   at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)     at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:910)   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:818)   at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)   at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)   at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225) Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)   at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:176)     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)   at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:899)    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:106)   ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepDescriptorCache.getPublicCache(StepDescriptorCache.java:48)     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepDescriptorCache.invalidateGlobalCache(StepDescriptorCache.java:55)  ... 13 more
```

i checked few solutions like delete all plugins etc, but did not work , any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

before updating any plugin , take a backup of plugins folder.
i just restored the plugins folder and i am able to boot the jenkins now